# merge branch that was created from old commit to master

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I created a new branch from old master-commit. 
When trying to merge it with master using

```
git checkout master
git merge newbranch
```

I am getting

> `Already up to date`

although it is a different code.

Of course there is an option to go back several commits (using `git reset`) but this is not what I am looking for. I want to `push`/`merge` the newly created branch to master.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: It should work just doing a normal merge, can you put exactly the commands that you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go back to the master branch (`git checkout master`) and then merge in your new branch (`git merge <newbranch>`). That will pull over the changes from that branch into your master branch.

Read more here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: tried that , got already up to date , thanks, I have edited my question so it will be clearer

Comment: It sounds like you already did the merge. Does `git log master` show commits from both branches? If not, you may need to tell use the full set of commands you've tried to merge these branches. Did the link offer any assistance? I'm afraid I can't offer much more help without knowing more about your specific circumstances. It sounds like you've done the right thing from what I know so far.