# How to merge a branch made from an old commit

Tags: git, merge, branch, commit

This is the same question as [merge branch that was created from old commit to master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851027/merge-branch-that-was-created-from-old-commit-to-master) which never got a complete answer.
So I have the following situation on my `development` branch

```
$ git commit
commit 1
```

All is good.

Change files `a`, `b`, and `c`.

```
$ git commit
commit 2
```

Automated testing failed

Rollback files

```
$ git commit
commit 3
$ git checkout 2
$ git branch failed
```

Find error in `b`, fix, test

```
$ git commit
commit 4
$ git checkout development
$ git merge failed
```

ONLY `b` IS MERGED.  `a` and `c` are not.  I confirm by physically looking at the files and note that they are different.  A `git diff development..failed` further demonstrates them as different.

I need all the files.  When I do a `git merge` I expect everything to be brought across, for them to be basically identical.

I can make a trivial change to the files to force it to merge, I can take a copy of the `failed` branch and copy the files into `development` manually and check them in that way, I'm sure there's something else I can do with just forcing git to take `failed` as the new `development` branch, but these all feel like the wrong answer, especially when I consider that my real situation is a lot more complex than just three files and the chance of human error is great.

How do I do this correctly?  How can I properly merge all the files that are different from this `failed` branch back into `development`?

Thank you.

Comment: Am I understanding you right? You want that `a`  and `c` are the same as in *commit 2* after merging `failed` (which started on *commit 2*)?

Comment: If I do `git checkout 2` and then `git branch failed`, I don't get a branch created called `failed`. I remain in a detached HEAD state and would lose any commits on switching back to `development` as the git warnings state.  Are you sure the `failed` branch is created?

Comment: I probably misremembered exactly what I did, I've been banging my head a lot against the man pages trying to figure out how to do what I want to do but the end result is that I have a branch "failed" which is "commit 2" which I have then modified file "b".  I want to merge this branch, all three files, back into development (where others have since also made changes but not to these particular files).

Comment: How should git know that it should merge `a` and `c` if you have made no changes to them on `failed`? You can discard **all** changes on `development` which were done after you branched of `failed` but you said that other developers have made changes too, and I doubt you want to lose these changes.

Comment: "How should git know that it should merge a and c if you have made no changes to them on failed?"  Yes, that is the question.

Comment: I've been able to rollback the revert, make the fix, and then cherry pick the recent changes (which didn't touch my a, b, or c files in the example, so no problem).  Now I just need to look up how to convince git that my "failed" branch is the definitive new code and just copy everything into development, which I'm hoping is much easier.  This still feels wrong though.

Comment: Everything would mean that you discard **all** changes on development. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: I do not.  I want to ultimately ignore just the "revert" commit, which is what my cherry-picking has done.  And that may be the answer, to simply revert and cherry pick.  I was hoping for something just a little more automated, though I honestly can't think of what that might be.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to simply revert the revert and merge from there.

In my specific situation other developers had already made changes to the reverted code which I needed to cherry-pick as well.