# How to partially revert changes made in a file in an old commit in a branch to the HEAD for that branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-checkout

Here is the situation

```
---1---2---3---4---5---6---(HEAD -> master)
       |
      fix
```

I made some changes after commit 2, and later realized that I wanted some *parts* of commit 2 back in my code. Specifically I removed functions f() and g() and added functions a() and b() in a source file in commit 3. ***I want to keep a() and b() in master, and at the same time get f() and g() back.***. Note that I do not want to revert an entire file in master to it's state at commit 2.

So I created a branch *fix* at commit 2, and tried to merge it into master

```
git checkout 3
git checkout -b fix
git checkout master
git merge fix
```

Here I get the message

```
Already up to date.
```

This is a duplicate of the question: [merge branch that was created from old commit to master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851027/merge-branch-that-was-created-from-old-commit-to-master), but I followed the steps suggested in the answer. That did not result in f() and g() being restored in master- in fact, it did not trigger *any* merge conflict.

This is an issue I have faced multiple times. I understand that because commit 2 is already a part of the history of master, it is, in some sense already merged into master. The state of the repository is not the same at 2 and HEAD, and I want to selectively get back a part of 2 at HEAD. As far as I know, the git-merge manual page does not specify how to do this.

Comment: what language are you working on? if it is java. there is very cool way of handling this case.

Comment: Just creating branches without making any code changes will not magically restore your code. After you made the branch, you have to make changes to restore the code, and then commit that change on the branch. Then you can merge it into master.

Comment: Hi, @j6t, I tried that. Created a dummy file and commited to *advance* the branch, so to speak. But when I merged that branch into master, only the new file was added, and the changes in the older file persisted.

Comment: @surajs1n nope, it's Python.

Comment: @brick But of course. You only get the changes merged that you make. (Since all you did was add a file, you only get the added file.) If you want to undo something, then you *have to undo* it, make a commit from it, and merge that.

Answer (score 1):

If the commands from your question are the only git commands we execute, than all we do is create a new branch from commit `3` and attempt to merge it into `master`. The reason this doesn't do anything is because, in `git`, a branch is just a label, a [movable pointer to one of the commits in your repository](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell#:%7E:text=A%20branch%20in%20Git%20is,branch%20pointer%20moves%20forward%20automatically.). To make any changes to our repository *we must create a new commit*.

If I understand your question correctly, we want to "undo" *only some of changes* to one of our files (as **a** and **b** were added and **f** and **d** were removed in a single commit).

One way to do this is `git restore`:

```
git restore -s <commit> <path> // Restore the file to how it was before the chanes.
git add -e                     // Stage changes you want to keep. May use a GUI tool instead.
git diff --cached              // Optional: confirm that your changes are correct.
git commit
git restore .                  // Drop all the changes we didn't want to keep.
```

## Step-by-step

1. Switch to your master branch and ensure you have no changes to file in question in your working tree
2. Restore the file to the state it was in before we deleted **a** and **b**:
   [`git restore --source <commit-before-changes> <path-to-file>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore)
   If you run `git diff` now, you should see that **a** and **b** are added back, while **f** and **d** are being deleted.
3. Manually stage hunks you want to keep. You can use a GUI of your preference or run [`git add --edit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#_editing_patches) which allows you to edit hunks for staging. If you go with the latter keep in mind that it won't change the file itself and instead will only select changes to be added to the index.
4. Confirm that the changes you chose to keep are as you expect: run [`git diff --cached`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgt--cachedltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203) and make sure you are not deleting anything and adding both **a** and **b** back.
5. Commit with `git commit` and drop all of the changes you decided not to keep with `git restore .`

Comment: Hi, tried to do this,
```git: 'restore' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar command is
 remote.```

Installed git-all instead of just git, still does not support restore. Nor does the man page show the command.

Also, in step 3 of the process which you have described,  will I be able to access the merge tags functionality which git provides (the >>>>>> HEAD thing)?

Comment: `git restore` was introduced in version 2.23, I would recommend upgrading to the latest - 2.27. If that's not an option, you can use `git checkout <commit> <path>` followed by `git reset` instead. An additional command is necessary because `checkout`, unlike `restore`, stages the changes.
    

After step 2 your file will appear exactly as it was in the commit you specify when calling `restore` / `checkout` and you will not get any conflict markers.